# Share the image on flickr

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, flickr

I am developing a app where i want to load the images on flickr. I have seen the Snap and Run project where i tried to share the image using my API key but cannot do it. Can anyone help me with this as I am not able to do this.

Comment: any code samples or read resources would help

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about this.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Stanford course for iOS development as there is a great sample app on using Flickr. Pay particular attention to the FlickrFetcher class http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall lecture 9 :)